# Reading in to Linked-List not Working correctly C++

Tags: c++, input, graph, linked-list

I have been stuck on this problem for hours will someone please help.

The input is in the following format

```
5
1 2  9.0
1 3 12.0
2 4 18.0
2 3  6.0
2 5 20.0
3 5 15.0
0
1 5
```

The first number is the number of vertexes in the graph. Then next lines up to 0 are the edges of the graph. With the first and second numbers being the vertexes and the third being how far the edge is between them. Trying to read in the data and store the edges into there locations in the List adjacency for that vertex. This example would make a graph with five vertexes with edges from 1 to 2&3. 2 to 4&3&1 etc also stores opposites EX. 2 1 9.0.
It is not storing the data correctly. When reading in each new data for each vertex overwrites the previous data. It is storing the data in multiple listCells because when printed out i get

```
1 3 12.000
1 3 12.000
2 5 20.000
2 5 20.000
2 5 20.000
2 5 20.000
3 5 15.000
3 5 15.000
3 5 15.000
```

So it is the write number of cells just wrong information.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int tracing= 1;

struct ListCell
{
   ListCell* next;
   int vertex;
   double weight;

   ListCell(int v, double w, ListCell* nxt)
   {
      vertex = v;
      weight = w;
      next = nxt;
   }
};

typedef ListCell* List;

struct Vertex
{
   bool signaled;
   long distance;
   List adjacency;    
};

struct Graph
{
   int     numVertices;
   Vertex* vertexInfo;

   Graph(int n)
   {
      numVertices = n;
      vertexInfo  = new Vertex[n+1];
      for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
         vertexInfo[i].signaled = false;
      }
   }
};

//==============================================================
//                   tail
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

   List tail(List L)
   {
      return L->next;
   }
//==============================================================
//                   isEmpty
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

   bool isEmpty(List L)
   {
      return L == NULL;
   }
//==============================================================
//                   readIn
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

Graph readIn()
{
   int g;
   int p1;
   int p2;
   float edge;
   scanf("%i ", &g);

   Graph myGraph(g);
   scanf("%i", &p1);
   while(p1 != 0)
   {
      scanf("%i", &p2);
      scanf("%f", &edge);

      if(tracing >0)
      {
         printf("Edge from %i to %i is %5.3f\n", p1, p2, edge);
      }

      myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency = new ListCell 
      (p2,edge,myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency);


      myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency = new ListCell
      (p1, edge, myGraph.vertexInfo[p2].adjacency);

      scanf("%i", &p1);
   }
   return myGraph;
}

//==============================================================
//                   printOut
//==============================================================
// 
//==============================================================

void printOut(Graph myGraph)
{  
   int n;
   int length = myGraph.numVertices;
   float d;
   List p;

   printf("There are %i vertices.\n", length);
   printf("The edges are as follows. \n\n");
   for(int i=1; i<=length; i++)
   {
      p= myGraph.vertexInfo[i].adjacency;
      for(p=p; !isEmpty(p); p=tail(p))
      {
         n = myGraph.vertexInfo[i].adjacency -> vertex;
         d = myGraph.vertexInfo[i].adjacency -> weight; 
         if(i<n)
         {
            printf("%i %i %7.3f \n",i,n,d);
         }
      }
   }
}
//==============================================================
//                   main
//==============================================================

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Graph myGraph = readIn();
   printOut(myGraph);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really hate seeing typedefs of pointers to "remove" the need to have a *. Also, if you are really trying to use C++, use member functions.

Comment: ... and iostream extraction operators.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code.  The first thing and probably the most glaring is this:

```
myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency = new ListCell 
   (p2,edge,myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency);
```

you call this in the input loop.  Look at your first vertex you input (1).  You input this twice, one time for "1 2 9.0", and again for "1 3 12.0".  The variable p1 doesn't change (it remains at 1), but you're overwriting the first input with the second input.

So you not only have an error in the input, you have a memory leak since you're creating a ListCell dynamically, and overwriting the previous dynamically allocated ListCell.

Maybe an array is not what you should use as a vertexInfo.  Maybe it should be a map of vertex to vertices/distances:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int,double>>>
```

where the key is the vertex, and the inner vector is a vector of all the adjacent vertices and distances (each one represented as a pair).

Comment: I have to use an array for vertexInfo. but shouldn't `myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency = new ListCell 
   (p2,edge,myGraph.vertexInfo[p1].adjacency);` create a new cell each time in the adjacency list for vertex(p1) and then store the info in the new cell?

Comment: It will not add to to the linked list but overwrite it entirely.

Comment: No. You are reading too much into that line of code. C++ doesn't "retain" values like this. You are taking adjacency and replacing the value with a new one. No different than if you did this: `int adjacency = 1; adjacency = 2; ` What is the value of adjacency? It is 2, so what happened to the 1 that was stored before? It's gone.

Comment: @DMG - if you "have to use an array", then you need to come up with a different plan to store your vertices, because the one you have now isn't going to work.  Also, if you used your debugger, you should have seen that on the second input of the 1 vertex, your first input went poof and disappeared.

Comment: @DMG - what you probably should have done is do what you stated -- that is "add to adjacency".  Right now, you're overwriting it, not adding to it.  To "add to adjacency" requires you to know how to manipulate your adjacency so that it appends items to the list.